# morphism between two princial bundle over the same mainfold?

Tags: lie-groups, principal-bundles, morphism

Let $ \pi : P \rightarrow B$ and $\pi' ; Q \rightarrow B$  be two principal  G- bundles.

Why this is true:

If $f : P \rightarrow Q $ is a morphism of the pricipal G-bundles P and Q ( i.e. $f(p.g)= f(p).g, \forall p \in P, \forall g \in G $), then $ \pi'\circ f = \pi $ ?

Comment: Isn't a morphism of principal G-bundles (or even more generally fiber bundles) required to preserve fibers (so automatically satisfying the property $\pi' \circ f=\pi$)?

Comment: I find it in two references that the definition of  a morphism of pricinpal bundles is required to be just a G-equivariant map! One of the references I've checked is the notes   given in the answer of this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794067/principal-bundle-morphism-preserves-fundamental-group.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the what you're using the morphisms for, but sometimes it is useful to consider a more general notion of morphisms.  Given $\pi:P\rightarrow B$ and $\pi': P'\rightarrow B'$, you can define a morphism to be a pair $f:P\rightarrow P'$ and $g:B\rightarrow B'$ for which $\pi'\circ f = g\circ \pi$.  You recover the "usual" notion of morphism by insisting $g = Id_B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true as stated. For an easy counter example, let $P=Q=B \times G$, the trivial bundle. Then, given any nonidentity map $f:B \to B$ you get a map $P \to Q$ defined by $(x,g) \mapsto (f(x),g)$. This is certainly equivariant, but it doesn't satisfy the property you ask for.

There is a condition missing from the source you cite. Indeed, the answer at the linked page says that a morphism is an equivariant *fiber bundle* map, this means that it maps over the identity (i.e. satisfies the condition you ask for). The notes you mention just forgot to say this, its implicit in everything happening over the base space.

Comment: Thanks a lot @James Cameron for your nice answer!

Comment: @asma You're welcome, I should mention that those linked notes from Steve Mitchell are really good, I think that's the best place to leave about principal bundles from a homotopy theoretic point of view.

Comment: @Jamed Cameron, thank you for your suggestion! Actually, yes I've started using them these days in order   to better  understand principal bundles, and so far I can agree with you, they  very helpful!